# Netbeans Struts-config.xml action configuration

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have a problem when using Netbeans with Java EE and JSP.

I have a login form and when I'm logged in I'm forwarded to the page `LoginSucessful.jsp`. I have another page (`ListeArticleInventaire.jsp`) where my articles are listed.

My problem is:

I wanna link my `ListeArticleInventaire.jsp` with my java class `ListeArticleAction.jsp`, so that when the page is requested it executes the java class.

My struts-config.xml :

```
<global-exceptions>

</global-exceptions>

<global-forwards>

</global-forwards>

<action-mappings>
    <action input="/loginForm.jsp" name="UserLoginActionForm" path="/login" scope="session" type="com.myapp.struts.UserLoginAction">
        <forward name="success" path="/displayList.do"/>
         <!-- <forward name="success" path="/displayList.do"/> -->
    </action>

    <action input="/ListeArticleInventaire.jsp" name="listArticle" path="/displayList" scope="session" type="com.myapp.struts.ListeArticleAction">
        <forward name="display" path="/ListeArticleInventaire.jsp"/>
    </action>

    <action forward="/loginOut.jsp" path="/logout"/>
```

ListeArticleAction.java:

```java
public class ListeArticleAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    /* forward name="success" path="" */
    private static final String DISPLAY = "display";

    /**
     * This is the action called from the Struts framework.
     *
     * @param mapping The ActionMapping used to select this instance.
     * @param form The optional ActionForm bean for this request.
     * @param request The HTTP Request we are processing.
     * @param response The HTTP Response we are processing.
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("it works!");
        return mapping.findForward(DISPLAY);
    }
}
```

The problem is just on linking. When my `ListeArticleInventaire` is requested I don't see the output 'it works!', which means that the class was no called.